# Get the days of a week given day name

Tags: c#, datetime

```
        public class Date
        {
        public int mm;
        public int dd;

        public Date(int get_mm, int get_dd)
        {
            mm = get_mm;
            dd = get_dd;
        }            

        int day = (int)(daysofweek)Enum.Parse(typeof(daysofweek), DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString());
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
        int day_fetch = i - day;
        Console.WriteLine(Date date = new Date(DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day + day_fetch));
        }
```

I made this but it doesn't seems working well
What can i do to make it work and how can i solve that problem if the date is for example March 30(The first 2 days is on march but the others are on April)

Comment: `DateTime` objects have a method called `AddDays` which allows to build new `DateTime`s based on the amount (even negative) of days you want to add.

Comment: It's not clear at all (to me) what you're trying to do. Can you give some sample inputs and outputs? Also note that since you haven't overridden `ToString()` you won't see the values of your custom `Date` class in the console.

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't seems working well".  Also, `daysofweek` is not a type and `Date date = new Date(DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day + day_fetch)` passed as a parameter is not valid, so please show the actual, _compilable_ code you are using.

Comment: Also, you don't need to parse the string representation of `DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek` because you already have the value: `DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek`.  It seems like you're just trying to print the day names from tomorrow for the following week, which you could do with something like `for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) { DateTime date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(i); Console.WriteLine($"Date: {date:d}; DayOfWeek: {date.DayOfWeek}"); }`.

Comment: Enum.Parse() falls flat on its face when localization matters.  The user name is a hint, gaborbozo, Hungarian and English don't mix that well.  Do complete your SO profile to get the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// 30 March
var dateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
var dayOfWeek = dateTime.DayOfWeek;

// Figure out the first day on the calendar
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
Calendar calendar = ci.Calendar;
var firstDayOfWeek = ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

// date (in this case Now) is exlcusive
var daysToBeginningOfWeek = dayOfWeek - firstDayOfWeek;

// Days from beginning of the week to date
for (var i = daysToBeginningOfWeek; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var dt = dateTime.AddDays(-i);
    Date date = new Date(dt.Month, dt.Day);
    Console.WriteLine(date);
}

// Days after date to end of the week
var daysToEndOfWeek = 7 - daysToBeginningOfWeek - 1;
for (var i = 1; i <= daysToEndOfWeek; i++)
{
    var dt = dateTime.AddDays(i);
    Date date = new Date(dt.Month, dt.Day);
    Console.WriteLine(date);
}
```

You will also need to take first day of the week into consideration because not all calendars are from Sunday to Saturday.